# Import doesn't work when using relative path. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to import a File. When I use the Relative Path I get an error.
But when I use the full path. There is no problem. No idea why and it's bugging me a lot.

So when I use:

```
import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar/SearchBar.js';
```

I get:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/SearchBar/SearchBar.js'
```

But when I use the Full Path:

```
import SearchBar from /Users/xxx/Proyects/DevProyect/src/components/SearchBar/SearchBar.js
```

It runs ok.

Comment: What is the path of the file you're making the import from?

Comment: I'm going to bet it's not in the root of `src`...

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your folder structure so that we can see where is your `searchbar.js` file located and in which file you are trying to import it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where you're making the import from.

> In this case `./` is the current folder you're working on

That being said, if the file you're making import from is inside `src` folder then you can use

```
import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar/SearchBar.js';
```

and if the file you're making import from is inside `components` folder for example then you can use

```
import SearchBar from './SearchBar/SearchBar.js';
```

since both SearchBar folder and the file you're working on are in the same folder/directory.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I looked all the files all over again. I had a repeated DevFolder in my user location. So when I was using the . to state my current folder I wasn't going to the folder I needed.
I spent like 5 hours looking at the code and the problems was in folder all along.

Comment: Glad I could help