# Javascript doesn't recognize relative path imports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import

[image] This is my projects structure in Webstorm

if I import Objects.js by this line it works

```
import * as Objects from "../../ecosystem/js/world/Objects.js";
```

but if I swtich to any of these

```
import * as Objects from "../js/world/Objects.js";
import * as Objects from "./js/world/Objects.js";
import * as Objects from "js/world/Objects.js";
```

It doesnt work and gives error `GET http://localhost:63342/js/world/Objects.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

I suspect this is because the network request is `Request URL: http://localhost:63342/js/world/Objects.js` which lacks ecosystem folder. How can I solve this in a clean way?

I create classes and export them at the end of `Objects.js` file as follows.

I looked into these links but still couldn't solve my issue:

[Import doesn't work when using relative path. JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62907256/import-doesnt-work-when-using-relative-path-javascript)

[How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

`export {Sphere, LightIndicator, MouseFollower, Terrain, Box};`